# Force syncdb to reset schema

Tags: database, django, orm, django-models

I am developing on my localhost a new project. As I am the only developer and the project is not yet online I don't want/need to use migrations (yet).

Also because the project is in early development stage, DB schema needs to be updated very often, so it's important to do it fast. Data can be lost.

Is there a way how to force syncdb to update the schema even when it already exists? Or perhaps a series of commands that will do this?

Currently I am dropping tables manually using external SQL client and then running syncdb ... but it get's tedious - especially because of constraint errors etc.

Is there a better/faster way how to refresh schema after Django models were modified?,

Comment: If you are planning on using migrations in the future and need them now, why aren't you using them?

Comment: @Andy Because it takes much more time to update schema using South than by dropping tables and re-running syncdb and there is no real benefit of using migrations at this point.

Comment: Running `./manage.py schemamigration <app> --auto` to create the migration and `./manage.py migrate <app>` to run the migration is much more time?

Comment: @Andy it also asks for default values etc :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Django, I use reset:

```
python manage.py reset <app-name>
```

Will drop and re-sync all tables in that app for you. It's been removed in 1.5 I think, maybe for the upcoming south integration.

Comment: Yeah I can't find the reset in dev :(

Answer (score 0):

When in dev I just usually drop the entire database and create another one. I use postgresql on linux where there are CLI commands that allow you to do this quickly:

```
dropdb dbname

createdb dbname

python manage.py syncdb
```